# React Native “AppLoading threw an unexpected error when loading” error

Tags: javascript, react-native, android-studio

1. [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SPx1g.png)

   ---
2. [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gZGsV.png)

   ---

I encountered such an error while running my React Native project on the Android emulator and I got this error even though I did not make any changes to the code. It works fine on a normal device, but not on android studio emulator.

I will be glad if you help me.

app.js, package.json and MealsNavigator files are attached.

**app.js**

```
import React, { useState } from 'react';
import { Text, View } from 'react-native';
import * as Font from 'expo-font';
import AppLoading from 'expo-app-loading';
import { enableScreens } from "react-native-screens";
    
import MealsNavigator from './navigation/MealsNavigator';
    
    enableScreens();
    
    const fetchFonts = () => {
      return Font.loadAsync({
        'open-sans': require('./assets/fonts/OpenSans-Regular.ttf'),
        'open-sans-bold': require('./assets/fonts/OpenSans-Bold.ttf')
      });
    };
    
    export default function App() {
      const [fontLoaded, setFontLoaded] = useState(false);
    
      if (!fontLoaded) {
        return (
          <AppLoading
            startAsync={fetchFonts}
            onFinish={() => setFontLoaded(true)}
            onError={(error)=> console.warn(error)}
          />
        );
      }
    
      return <MealsNavigator />;
    }
```

---

**package.json**

```
    {
  "name": "rn-meal",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "main": "node_modules/expo/AppEntry.js",
  "scripts": {
    "start": "expo start",
    "android": "expo start --android",
    "ios": "expo start --ios",
    "web": "expo start --web",
    "eject": "expo eject"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "@expo/vector-icons": "^12.0.5",
    "@react-native-community/masked-view": "^0.1.11",
    "@react-navigation/native": "^6.0.8",
    "expo": "~44.0.0",
    "expo-app-loading": "~1.3.0",
    "expo-font": "^10.0.5",
    "expo-status-bar": "~1.2.0",
    "react": "17.0.1",
    "react-dom": "17.0.1",
    "react-native": "0.64.3",
    "react-native-gesture-handler": "~2.1.0",
    "react-native-paper": "^4.11.2",
    "react-native-reanimated": "~2.3.1",
    "react-native-safe-area-context": "3.3.2",
    "react-native-screens": "^3.10.2",
    "react-native-web": "0.17.1",
    "react-navigation": "^4.4.4",
    "react-navigation-drawer": "^2.7.2",
    "react-navigation-header-buttons": "^6.3.1",
    "react-navigation-material-bottom-tabs": "^2.3.5",
    "react-navigation-stack": "^2.10.4",
    "react-navigation-tabs": "^2.11.2",
    "react-router-dom": "^6.0.0-beta.8"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@babel/core": "^7.12.9"
  },
  "private": true
}
```

---

**MealsNavigator.js**

```
import { Platform, Text } from 'react-native';
import { createStackNavigator } from 'react-navigation-stack';
import { createAppContainer } from 'react-navigation';
import { createBottomTabNavigator } from 'react-navigation-tabs';
import { Ionicons } from '@expo/vector-icons';
import { createMaterialBottomTabNavigator } from "react-navigation-material-bottom-tabs";
import { createDrawerNavigator } from 'react-navigation-drawer';

import CategoriesScreen from '../screens/CategoriesScreen';
import CategoryMealsScreen from '../screens/CategoryMealsScreen';
import FavoritesScreen from "../screens/FavoritesScreen";
import MealDetailScreen from '../screens/MealDetailScreen';
import FiltersScreen from "../screens/FiltersScreen";
import Colors from '../constants/Colors';

const defaultNavigationOptions = {
  headerStyle: {
    backgroundColor: Platform.OS === "android" ? Colors.primaryColor : "",
  },
  headerTitleStyle: {
    fontFamily: "open-sans-bold",
  },
  headerBackTitleStyle: {
    fontFamily: "open-sans",
  },
  headerTintColor: Platform.OS === "android" ? "white" : Colors.primaryColor,
  headerTitle: "A Screen",
}

const MealsNavigator = createStackNavigator({
  Categories: {
    screen: CategoriesScreen,
  },
  CategoryMeals: {
    screen: CategoryMealsScreen,
  },
  MealDetail: MealDetailScreen,
},
  {
    mode: "modal",
    defaultNavigationOptions: defaultNavigationOptions
  });

const FavNavigator = createStackNavigator({
  Favorites: FavoritesScreen,
  MealDetail: MealDetailScreen,
}, {
  mode: "modal",
  defaultNavigationOptions: defaultNavigationOptions
})

const tabScreenConfig = {
  Meals: {
    screen: MealsNavigator,
    navigationOptions: {
      tabBarIcon: (tabInfo) => {
        return <Ionicons name="ios-restaurant" size={25} color={tabInfo.tintColor} />;
      },
      tabBarColor: Colors.primaryColor,
      tabBarLabel: Platform.OS === "android" ? <Text 
      style={{fontFamily: "open-sans-bold"}}>Meals
      </Text> : "Meals"
    },
  },
  Favorites: {
    screen: FavNavigator,
    navigationOptions: {
      tabBarLabel: "Favorite !",
      tabBarIcon: (tabInfo) => {
        return <Ionicons name="heart-sharp" size={25} color={tabInfo.tintColor} />;
      },
      tabBarColor: Platform.OS === "android" ? <Text 
      style={{fontFamily: "open-sans-bold"}}>Favorites
      </Text> : "Favorites",
    }
  },
}

const MealsFavTabNavigator = Platform.OS === "android"
  ? createMaterialBottomTabNavigator(tabScreenConfig, {
    activeTintColor: "white",
    shifting: true,
    barStyle: {
      backgroundColor: Colors.primaryColor,
    }
  })
  : createBottomTabNavigator(tabScreenConfig, {
    tabBarOptions: {
      labelStyle: {
        fontFamily: "open-sans",
      },
      activeTintColor: Colors.accentColor,
    }
  });

const FiltersNavigator = createStackNavigator({
  Filters: FiltersScreen
}, {
  mode: "modal",
  /*navigationOptions: {
    drawerLabel: "Filters!!!"
  },*/
  defaultNavigationOptions: defaultNavigationOptions
});

const MainNavigator = createDrawerNavigator({
  MealsFav: {
    screen: MealsFavTabNavigator,
    navigationOptions: {
      drawerLabel: "Meals"
    },
  },
  Filters: FiltersNavigator,
}, {
  contentOptions: {
    activeTintColor: Colors.accentColor,
    labelStyle: {
      fontFamily: "open-sans-bold",
    }
  }
});

export default createAppContainer(MainNavigator);
```

Comment: consider adding your `MealsNavigator ` screen too probably the problem is comming from there

Comment: I added MealsNavigator.js